# How to use the service in backgroundtask for downloading data's from server in android?

Tags: android, service, background, threadpool, android-progressbar

I want to download a data from the server.so the current activity shows the download progress bar in the screen.if i move to another activity and come back to download page activity page,i want to show downloading cursor with downloading rate and size without interupt.what type of service shall i use in android ?can anybody give me some logic or code in android?

Answer (score 0):

Use service to start download process. To download data use AsyncTask.

Something like this:

```
//in activity
Intent service = new Intent (this, Service.class);
service.setAction(ACTION);//ACTION is some String constant to determine action
startService(service);

// in service

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION )){
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask();
task .execute();
}

return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;}
```

So, you start download and even if you will close your activity, process will not be terminated.
To check downloading process you can use local broadcast reciever.